# Notice: Undefined offset: 3 php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The data displayed here comes from two tables:

First column has `fname`,

and the second column contains the `sum`,

This code creates a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
| First Name | Total  |
+---------------------+
| Pedro      | 19     |
| Carlos     | 10     |
| Albert     | (NULL) |
+---------------------+
```

And because Albert don't have any value for Total I get this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3

Can someone explain me what this is, and if is possible to fix

```
<?php foreach($rowstudent as $k=>$rowst): ?>
<tr>
<th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th> 

<th> <?php echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';?></th>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use `isset` to check if value exists or not.

Comment: @Rikesh Im tryign but I don't know how

Comment: When you don't know know... google it. I don't mean it to say that in a condescending fashion but there is clearly no attempt to try to fix it yourself, especially when someone provided you excellent direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick fix to your bug :

```
<?php foreach($rowstudent as $k=>$rowst): ?>
<tr>
<th><?php echo '' . htmlentities($rowst['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '';?></th> 

<th> <?php echo ' ' . htmlentities(isset($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum'])?$rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum']:'', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';?></th>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: still getting the same

Comment: I won't downvote this answer because it does a terrific job implementing the ternary operator and minimizing the amount of code necessary to solve this issue. However, I think a small explanation would do wonders for the OP and future readers. Simply answering the question with "here is the code" doesn't provide much value and makes this a solution for an isolated case.

Answer (score 1):

In $rowstudentpoints array 2 nd index sum value was not set so it displays the notice message.
Use below code for avoid the notice message.

```
<th> <?php echo ' ' . $rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum']?htmlentities($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'):'' . '<br>';?></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your points array have only two values.Thats why it is showing undefined offse.

Try like this

```
<?php 
if(isset($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum']))
{
echo ' ' . htmlentities($rowstudentpoints[$k]['sum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '<br>';
}
?>
```

If the value is there then only it will print